# jQueryUI - Detect if element is beeing dragged

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I want to get the position of an element when it is beeing dragged.

My code so far:

```
$(document).ready(function(){


    $("p").text($("div").position().left);
    $("p").text($("div").position().top);

    $("div").draggable();

})
```

This only gets the position when the page loads. I want to detect whenever the div is beeing dragged so I can write its position in the p tag.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
$('#dragThis').draggable(
    {
        drag: function(){
            var offset = $(this).offset();
            var xPos = offset.left;
            var yPos = offset.top;
            $('#posX').text('x: ' + xPos);
            $('#posY').text('y: ' + yPos);
        }
    });
```

**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/DGbT3/1160/)**

Answer (score 1):

You should have a look at the events section of the jQuery official documentation:
http://jqueryui.com/draggable/#events

The `drag` event will be raised while being dragged and from there you can get the offset. For example:

```
$(this).offset().left;
$(this).offset().top;
```